# Field Calculator & Python 3 String Reclass Warning

Tags: python, arcgis

I am throwing a python 3 warning in ArcPro which states:

> Warning 002858: Certain rows set to NULL due to error while evaluating python expression: File "string", line 3, in reclass

The code I am using is as follows:

`UpOrDown_PerAcre = reclass(!GP2040Area!,!UpOrDownNum!)`

**Code Block**

`def reclass(GP2040AREA, UpOrDownNum):
    if (UpOrDownNum != 0 or UpOrDownNum != 999):
        UpOrDown_PerAcre = GP2040AREA * UpOrDownNum
        return UpOrDown_PerAcre`

What I am trying to do is, for every cell in UpOrDownNum that is not 0 or 999, output the multiple of cell GP2040ArEA and UpOrDownNum in the new column UpOrDown_PerAcre.

Line 3 would, from my understanding, be "UpOrDown_PerAcre = GP2040AREA * UpOrDownNum" which is saying the output is a string? I did have the if statement classified as `if (UpOrDownNum == int and UpOrDownNum != 0 or UpOrDownNum != 999):` because there -are- null values in UpOrDownNum which may be throwing a 'string' warning but it was the same after removing that from the if statement.

Where exactly did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps check UpOrDownNum is not None (Python's version of null):

```
def reclass(GP2040AREA, UpOrDownNum):
    if (UpOrDownNum is not None and (UpOrDownNum != 0 or UpOrDownNum != 999)):
        UpOrDown_PerAcre = GP2040AREA * UpOrDownNum
        return UpOrDown_PerAcre
    else:
        return None # or 0 or -1 or whatever you want to signify the UpOrDown_PerAcre wasn't calculated
```

Comment: Pete, I'll give that tweak a shot and get back with the results.

Comment: What do you want to return if UpOrDownNum is None or equal to 0 or 999?

Comment: I'm throwing an Error 999999: something unexpected caused the tool to fail. Cannot acquire a lock. I'll trouble shoot this and return. What I want to do is, if the field IS NOT none, and if it is NOT 0 or 999, to output into the UpOrDown_PerAcre column the multiple of GP2040AREA and UpOrDownNum. So, if GP2040AREA is 1 acre, and UpOrDownNum is not null, 0, or 999, and has a value of say, 80, UpOrDown_PerAcre would be 1 x 80 or 80.

Comment: That Cannot acquire a lock error can be annoying. Usually closing/reopening the map document or Pro project fixes for me. My question above was trying to get at what does "reclass" return when the if statement is not met? I'll edit my answer.

Comment: That tweak is still throwing the WARNING 002858: Certain rows set to NULL due to error while evaluating python expression:   File "string", line 3, in reclass. The closing and re-opening of the map project did fix the Error 999999 problem though.